# How to configure a bridge between two interfaces in Ubuntu server 14.04?

Tags: linux, networking, ubuntu-14.04

I am trying to configure a bridge between two interfaces `em1` and `em2` in Ubuntu server 14.04.
This is my configuration:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto em1 
iface em1 inet dhcp

auto em2
iface em2 inet dhcp

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
address 10.1.1.11
network 10.1.1.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.1.1.255
gateway 10.1.1.1
dns-nameservers 10.1.1.1
bridge_ports em1 em2
brige_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

But it doesn't work. What is incorrect with my configuration?

Comment: Can you elaborate on the *it doesn't work* statement ?

Comment: when i use ifconfig command just shows the interfaces and it doesn't setup the bridge .

Comment: If you are going to bridge those two interfaces  you really shouldn't be trying to also configure them with DHCP.  Remove the stanzas for em1, em2 completely.  Also, do you have the `bridge-utils` package installed?

Comment: tanx @Zoredache.my bridge-utils had problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto em1 
iface em1 inet manual

auto em2
iface em2 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
metric 0
address 10.1.1.11
network 10.1.1.0
netmask 255.255.255.0
broadcast 10.1.1.255
gateway 10.1.1.1
dns-nameservers 10.1.1.1
bridge_ports em2
brige_stp off
bridge_fd 0
bridge_maxwait 0
```

If em1 is on a different subnet, then you can copy the br0 to a br1 section with subnet info and change metric 0 to 1.

If they are on the same subnet, and you want to use both, you'll need to bond them. Install ifenslave and configure bonding. I can give you a sample config for that too, but be forewarned, bridges and bonding don't go together if you're using this in a virtual environment. You'll need to use macvtap interfaces.

Comment: tank you for your helping